# how to exempt a file from Open File Security Warnings

Tags: windows, security, warnings, group-policy

I want to exempt a specific file from the Windows Open File Security Warnings.

I found a solution at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1043010-disable-open-file-security-warning-for-a-single-file, which depends on the user having access to Internet Explorer.  But I'm running the current version of Win10 which no longer includes Internet Explorer.

I've found other solutions that recommend adding the file to an exclusion list in Group Policy Editor, but I can not find the exclusion list.

Any suggestions about where I could learn how to fix this problem for specific files (not file types) would be much appreciated.  Thank you.
Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exempt a specific file from these warnings, you can consider the following options:

Unblock the File Or Group Policy (Which is more advanced)

For unblock the file go to properties by right click in properties look at the bottom, there may be an "Unblock" checkbox or button. Click "Unblock" if it's available. then apply and click ok to save changes

For Group Policy Editor : in run windows type `gpedit.msc` to configure the "Inclusion list for moderate risk file types" policy. Add the file extension you want to exempt from the Open File Security Warning to the list. Note: this method will be applied to all files and folder in pc :)

Comment: Thank you for trying, but there is no "Unblock" checkbox or button on the file, which sometimes is a VBScript or a Powershell file.   I don't want to exempt all VBScripts or all Powershell files from the Open File Warning.